# Used git push --mirror to copy files from existing repo to the new repo. Now commits to the new repo are causing commits to the existing repo

Tags: git, github, push, mirror, git-server

we in our team created a new repo in github https://new-parent-cicd-pipeline.git from an existing repo https://existing-parent-cicd-pipeline.git using the commands

$ git clone --bare https://existing-parent-cicd-pipeline.git
Then, go into the repository.
$ cd existing-parent-cicd-pipeline
Finally, use the --mirror flag to copy everything in your local Git repository into the new repo.
$ git push --mirror https://new-parent-cicd-pipeline.git

When we pushed a few commits to the new repo 'https://new-parent-cicd-pipeline.git', surprisingly the same commits were also being commited into the existing repo 'https://existing-parent-cicd-pipeline.git'. We also forgot to update the groupid, artifactid, SCM connections in the new repo pom.xml. Later, we wanted to remove those commits from the existing repo so we thought removing those changes from the new repo will remove the commits from the existing repo, but, it did not happen. Now the new commits to new repo are not happening on the existing repo. Looks like there is some reference between the existing and new repos which we are unable to figure out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The original idea was just to copy all the files from the existing repo to the new repo. And now we want to remove that reference and if possible delete the new repo and create a new one from scratch, which we are scared of doing thinking any deletion on new repo will also delete files from the existing repo.

Did not try anything.

Comment: Where are you pushing commits from, a working local copy? From that, what's the output from `git remote -v` and `git branch -avv`? Are you still using the directory used during `push --mirror`?

Comment: `git clone --bare https://existing-parent-cicd-pipeline.git` creates a local "bare clone" directory called `existing-parent-cicd-pipeline.git` [with the .git extension], but you wrote `cd existing-parent-cicd-pipeline` which isn't the same directory - are you sure you cd'd into the right directory?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.